# Como puedo hacer una busqueda mediante un select a la base de Datos

Tags: php, html

Bueno tengo realizado un select en donde muestro el nombre y apellidos de los jugadores ingresados en mi bases de datos. El codigo le tengo bien porque me muestra todo correctamente

```
<h3 class="insertar">Busque el Jugador que desees</h3>
<form action="entrenadorbuscar.php" method="POST">
<div class="buscar">
<table class='lis'>
<tr>
<td class='buscar'><select name="jugador">
<?php

include ("Funciones.php");
    $conexion=conectar();
    
    echo "<option> -------------- </option>";
    $consulta="select * from jugadores";    
    $filas=listar($conexion,$consulta);
    foreach($filas as $fila) {
         echo "<option>". $fila["Nombre"]." ".$fila["Apellidos"] . "</option>";
    }
    
    ?>
    </select></td>
```

Ahora quiero que cuando seleccione un jugador me muestre abajo toda la informacion de ese jugador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando selecciono un jugador no me hace nada no me muestra nada y ya nose como ponerlo para que lo haga

Este es el codigo con el cual quiero que me haga eso

```
if(isset($_POST["buscar"])){
        if(isset($_POST["jugador"])){
        $busqueda="select * from jugadores";    
        $filas=listar($conexion,$busqueda);
    foreach($filas as $fila) {
        echo"<tr>";
        echo "<td class='lis'>" . $fila["Dni"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='lis'>" . $fila["Nombre"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='lis'>" . $fila["Apellidos"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='lis'>" . $fila["FechaNacimiento"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='lis'>" . $fila["Categoria"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><img class='ins' src='".$fila["Foto"]."'></img></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }       
            echo "</table>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Con el DNI quiero indentificarlos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu código presenta 2 problemas a resolver:

1. En los `<option` te esta faltando indcar el `value`. El valor establecido en dicho atributo te permitirá saber cual fue el seleccionado.
2. Al realizar la consulta de búsqueda te esta faltando agregar la condición para filtrar los resultados.

#### Solución:

Al generar el listado de jugadores agregamos un `value` a cada una de las opciones:

```
<select name="jugador">
    <?php

    include ("Funciones.php");
    $conexion=conectar();
    
    echo "<option value=""> -------------- </option>";
    $consulta="select * from jugadores";    
    $filas=listar($conexion,$consulta);
    foreach($filas as $fila) {

         // AGREGAMOS UN VALOR A LAS OPCIONES
         echo "<option value='". $fila["Dni"]."'>" . 
              $fila["Nombre"]." ".$fila["Apellidos"] . "</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Luego al realizar la búsqueda, validamos si el valor ha sido enviado y aplicamos el filtro.

```
if(isset($_POST["buscar"])){
    
    // APLICAMOS FILTROS DE BÚSQUEDA
    $filtros = [];
    if(isset($_POST["jugador"]) && $_POST["jugador"] != ''){
        $filtros[] = "Dni = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST["jugador"])."'";
    }
    if (!empty($filtros)) {
        $filtros = " WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $filtros);
    } else {
        $filtros = '';
    }

    // AGREGAMOS EL FILTRO A LA CONSULTA
    $busqueda="SELECT * FROM jugadores" . $filtros;
    $filas=listar($conexion,$busqueda);
    foreach($filas as $fila) {
        echo"<tr>";
        echo "<td class='lis'>" . $fila["Dni"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='lis'>" . $fila["Nombre"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='lis'>" . $fila["Apellidos"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='lis'>" . $fila["FechaNacimiento"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td class='lis'>" . $fila["Categoria"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td><img class='ins' src='".$fila["Foto"]."'></img></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

---

Referencias:

- [`PHP - mysqli_real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)
- [`PHP - implode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.implode)
- [`HTML - option`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/option)

Answer (score 1):

lo que pasa es que en el value del option no estás mandando nada puedes probar con esto en el `echo` del option.

```
foreach($filas as $fila) {
     echo "<option value=".$fila["Dni"].">". $fila["Nombre"]." ".$fila["Apellidos"] . " 
</option>";
}
```

Ahora en tu otro archivo puedes hacer uso de la variable de la siguiente manera, esto pensando en que Dni es tu identificador principal;

```
        $busqueda="select * from jugadores where Dni = ". $_POST["jugador"];
```

Answer (score 0):

1º) Necesitas añadir un value="" en cada  con el nombre de cada jugador.

2º) Para hacer lo que quieres necesitas utilizar AJAX o Fetch. Esto te permite enviar información de un formulario, desde un archivo HTML + JS hasta un archivo de PHP donde procesas la información de dicho formulario, de forma asíncrona. Es decir, te permite enviar los datos y procesarlos sin necesidad de recargar la página. Para utilizar AJAX necesitas tener jQuery (una librería de JS, imagino que lo conoces). A continuación te muestro como mandar el formulario con AJAX:

```
$("#botonBuscar").on("click", function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var formData = $('#idFormulario').serialize();
    obtenerInformacionDelJugador(formData)
}

function obtenerInformacionDelJugador(consulta){
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "entrenadorbuscar.php",
        data: consulta
    })
    .done(function(res){
        // Aqui recibes la información del usuario
        // que puedes utilizar mediante la variable 'res'
        var datosDelJugador = JSON.parse(res);
    })
}
```

Lo siguiente es crear un archivo PHP (entrenadorbuscar.php) donde le pases el nombre del jugador elegido en el . Después de pasarle el nombre del jugador mediante el formulario, lo recoges en ese archivo y haces una consulta a la base de datos:

```
$jugador = $_POST['jugador']
$query = mysqli_query = ($conn, "SELECT * FROM jugadores WHERE nombre = '$jugador'");
$infoDelJugador = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

echo json_encode($infoDelJugador);
```

Recoges esa información en .done(function(res){}) del archivo HTML. Puedes volver a pasarlo a array con `var datosDelJugador = JSON.parse(res)`

Después ya puedes utilizar ese array para lo que necesites.